# Plotting heat data (with pcolormesh or similar) fails in the edges of map (cartopy)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cartopy

I want to plot heat data on a map (Cartopy projection), but on the edges of the map, a frame of cells is created regardless of the size of the array. It was noticed, that the columns on the far left and far right have identical values.

Code:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()

heat_data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, heat_data.shape[1])
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, heat_data.shape[0])
ax.pcolormesh(lon, lat, np.transpose(heat_data), alpha = 0.2)
plt.show()
```

Outcome No1: [Result without transparency of the array (first and last columns have identical values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVsPS.png)

Outcome No2: [Result with transparent array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iVgY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Running the code you provided worked fine for me, producing a map with transparent pcolormesh. I believe this is the desired result?

[image: OP code and resultant map]

You also have a fencepost issues which may be causing the problem. Note that while you have made a 10 x 10 grid of cells, you specify lon and lat in a 10 x 10 grid  that includes the endpoints, mot the centers of the grid. This will confuse meshgrid. Could you try:

```
lat = np.linspace(-90, 90, heat_data.shape[1] +1)
lon = np.linspace(-180, 180, heat_data.shape[0] +1)
```

ie setting the edges of the blocks in the desired places.

Comment: That's an absolutely valid point! However, a follow-up question is that when the endpoints of a grid of cells are _beyond_ the "borders" of the map (the "borders" are for lat:-90,90 and long:-180,180), a frame of cells is created and those cells are also wrapped around, which is not the desired outcome.
As an example, in the above code I change only the lines with lat and lon as followed:
`lat = np.linspace(-95, 95, heat_data.shape[1] +1)
lon = np.linspace(-185, 185, heat_data.shape[0] +1)`

In a nutshell, I want to plot a grid of cells whose endpoints might be located outside of the map.

Comment: In the context of a sphere, having data outside of the bounds doesn't make physical sense. Where is 95 degrees North? You may want to think more about the data you pass to cartopy. It can't do anything sensible with data that doesn't map to a sphere so you get unexpected behaviour.
I suggest catching/cropping your data in the script before it tries to plot it if you really want to input data from outside of the coordinate limits.